# Angular2: Routing restrict child not working

Tags: angular, routes

My application has two main areas - one free and one private. Each one needs to have its own navbar and content. Because of that, I have a router outlet where I want both areas be rendered, one at a time - free area for any user and private area for logged in users.

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The FreeAreaComponent and RestrictAreaComponent, as said before, has its own navbar and content. Thinking on reusability of code, I keep the navbar and routes only the content as a child router outlet, like bellow:

**FreeAreaComponent**

```
<app-free-navbar></app-free-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**RestrictAreaComponent**

```
<app-restrict-navbar></app-restrict-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

On the free area, the default component that needs to be called is LandingComponent, that is my landing "page" (quotation because we know it is a SPA).

On the restrict area, the default one is WelcomeComponent, that is just a welcome "page" (quotation because we know it is a SPA).

Because of the behavior described above, the routing rules are like bellow:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes =[
{ path: '', component: FreeAreaComponent, children: [
  { path: '', component: LandingComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent }
]},
{ path: 'restrict', canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], component: RestrictAreaComponent, children: [
  { path: 'restrict', component: WelcomeComponent },
  { path: 'categories', component: CategoriesComponent }
]},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}];
```

When I try to reach the application, the free area (landing page) works fine, but it is not with the restrict area. The restrict navbar is rendered, but the content is not.

Some certainties I have:

- The RestrictAreaComponent is reached, because I put a console.log
  inside its ngOnInit and it was logged and the restrict navbar is rendered
- The canActivateChild rule is
  returning positive, I mean, it recognizes that the user is logged in.
- The WelcomeComponent is not being trigged. I put a console.log on its ngOnInit and nothing was logged at console.

If repeating the path of a route in its child is not a problem, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You realize that the 2 childrens of restricted can be reached by the following paths:

```
root/restrict/restrict -> WelcomeComponent (injected into router outlet in RestrictAreaComponent) 
root/resitrct/categories -> CategoriesComponent (injected into router outlet in RestrictAreaComponent)
```

If you are just navigating to `root/restricted`, you will **not** get any content injected in the router outlet inside of the `RestrictAreaComponent`.

If you want the `WelcomeComponent` to be injected on navigation to `root/restricted`, then u need to change the routing definiton.

UPDATE:
By changing to:

```
const appRoutes: Routes =[
{ path: '', component: FreeAreaComponent, children: [
  { path: '', component: LandingComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent }
]},
{ path: 'restrict', canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], component: RestrictAreaComponent, children: [
  { path: '', component: WelcomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'categories', component: CategoriesComponent }
]},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}];
```

You should now be able to navigate in the following way:

```
root/restrict -> WelcomeComponent (injected into router outlet in RestrictAreaComponent)
root/restrict/categories -> CategoriesComponent (injected into router outlet in RestrictAreaComponent)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I am new with Angular2 and because it works at free area, where I have (path: '') for both the root route and its child, it is not "of course" for me. Which kind of change you suggest on the routing definition?

Comment: Didnt wanted to sound rude, I just got the feeling that u were not an angular starter because the definition of the routing is in fact good. Ill edit my answer

Comment: You weren't rude. I just commented that it was not obvious for me, to make clear that I am a beginner and need more detailed help. About your contribution, it definitely solve the problem. I didn't tried that earlier, because make the path: '' sounds to me that I would be routing the FreeAreaComponent. Thank you!!!